# how to keep table data same in oracle and sql

Tags: ssis, data-warehouse

I am trying to build a database in sql server that replicates exact data present in tables in oracle production database. The database in sql server will be used for reporting and for analysis. I want every new or **updated** data in oracle tables to be present in sql server tables  in around 1 hour time span. Does sql server integration services helps on this? is there any tool that does this i.e. it makes sure that data present in oracle table and sql server table is always same( neglecting the 1 hour lag?)......

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you could look into: replication and SSIS. SQL Server replication allows you to [replicate data from Oracle to MSSQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151243.aspx) so that would be one way to handle the data copy. On the other hand, if you plan on doing data transformations, mappings etc. then you might want to use SSIS because it's a full ETL tool.

One important question is how you can identify new data in Oracle, because that may determine at least the first part of your solution. And you then have to decide what transformations are necessary once you've copied the data into SQL Server; perhaps you will need to run some stored procedures to clean the data and put it into reporting tables. Since your reporting system is a different platform from the source, you will need to handle data type transformations at some point, whatever solution you choose.

Your question is quite general, and it isn't really possible to say what you should do without a lot more detail about your environment, your requirements, your resources and so on. I suggest that you try to break down your task into smaller ones, and then you should be able to ask more specific questions.